# performance issue while running the web project using tomcat

Tags: oracle, tomcat, virtual-machine

I have build a environment on my laptop in which I build the tomcat server on my main OS (Windows 7) and Oracle server on Virtual Machine using VMWare on Linux OS (Redhat 5).

Now, When I am running my project, tomcat keeps loading the page and shows "waiting for localhost.." It takes 2-3 mins to load the dynamic page (which contain oracle data) however, static pages load very fast. I think it takes time to connect the VM Machine (Database Server).

**DB Connectivity Code**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    String Connecting_URL = Connecting_String + "@" + DB_IP_Addr + ":" + DB_Port + ":" + Oracle_Sid;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connecting_URL,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What block of code is being executed when you load the dynamic page with data from oracle? Have you tried running a query directly to database?

Comment: Thanks Alfabravo for your response..First level analysis I did..Actually SQL Query is not culprit because I created one page in which I didn't execute any SQL query..I only just create the database connection using JDBC driver (added in main query). It was also taking too much time..So, I was pretty sure that problem is with connectivity b/w DB server and web server

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving performance problems is to stop guessing and start measuring.
The more measurements you have, the closer you will be to reaching a solution.

The first thing I would log are the start timestamp and the end timestamp of a dynamic page load.
I would also measure the time it takes to run the query, the time it takes to obtain a connection from the connection pool (you are using a connection pool, right?)
I would watch the logs update live (using tail -f), to see if there was a big time difference between the time the browser sent the request and the dynamic page started processing. I would also watch CPU and RAM usage on the Oracle server while the query was running.

Finally, if the query time was the culprit, I would log out the query and run it outside the Tomcat environment, and try to optimize it by restructuring the query, adding indexes, fetching less data. Oracle can be a big help here, you can generate a query plan and watch for full table scans of large tables and other potentially expensive operation.

Only by measuring will you understand the source of the problem. In rare cases, it will be something very unusual(I once had this type of problem because of mis-configured DNS), but you have to rule out all the obvious possibilities one by one (my query is very bad, I do not have enough CPU/RAM for my database, I am not using a connection pool, etc...)

Comment: excellent advice. For some cases, where resources are available, its worth capturing data even before you have a problem, because when you do, you have evidence to show that "it used to work", and then you can question "what has changed?" Good luck to all!

Comment: Thanks Tony for your advise.. First level analysis I did..Actually SQL Query is not culprit because I created one page in which I didn't execute any SQL query..I only just create the database connection using JDBC driver (added in main query). It was also taking too much time..So, I was pretty sure that problem is with connectivity b/w DB server and web server. I have checked while executing resource were also available. (I have 8 GB memory on my laptop in which I have assigned 5GB memory to DB server). Now, I am blocked how to trouble shoot the issue.